# Domain of a piecewise continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, general-topology, functions, fourier-series

[image]

In the picture above what is the domain of the piecewise-continous function?

The first option is that the domain of the piecewise-continous function is [1,6]

The second option is that the domain is $\left [ 1,2 \right )\cup \left ( 2,3 \right ) \cup \left ( 3,4 \right )\cup \left ( 4,6 \right ]$

I could find the next definitions in web pages:

" The function Y(t) is piecewise continous on the closed interval [a,b], if there exists values $t_0,t_1,..,t_n$ with $a=t_0<t_1< ...<t_n=b$ such that Y(t) is continous in each of the open intervals $t_{k-1}<t<t_k$, for $k=1,2,...,n$ and has left-hand and right-hand limits at each of the values $t_k$, for k=0,1,2,...,n "

And the next one is from a student's course notes : " A function is said to be piecewise continous if its graph consists of a finite number of continous pieces on any part of its domain.The endpoints of the pieces must be well-defined"

Here "well-defined" is kind of ambiguous, as it can be interpreted that the endpoints of the pieces of the function must exist or that the existance of the limits of the endpoints of the pieces it's enough in order to be piecewise continous.

If the domain is [1,6], a second question arises. How can a function of any kind(here a piecewise-continous function) with domain [a,b] have points inside its domain where is not defined?

EDIT: [image]

Then, this graph would be from a piecewise continous function in [1,6]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement that the endpoints need to be well-defined doesn't mean that the function values are defined at the endpoints, just that we know what the endpoints are.  To say that the function is piecewise continuous on $[a,b]$ in the first definition is not to say that the domain of the function is $[a,b]$  That would be contradictory, as you have pointed out.

I don't agree with either of the proposed answers.  I don't agree with the first option because $2$ is not in the domain.  I don't agree with the second option because $1$ *is* in the domain.  My answer would be

$\left [ 1,2 \right )\cup \left ( 2,3 \right ) \cup \left ( 3,4 \right )\cup \left ( 4,6 \right ]$

Comment: I've just corrected it I meant $\left [ 1,2 \right )\cup \left ( 2,3 \right ) \cup \left ( 3,4 \right )\cup \left ( 4,6 \right ]$

Comment: Good, then that's my answer.

Comment: I think I'm mixing domain with piecewise-continuity. I added a picture in my question. Please, can you you tell me if  this function would be piecewise-continous in [1,6]too?

Comment: No it isn't, because the interval fro $4$ to $5$ isn't covered.  Look at the first definition of piecewise continuity carefully.  How could you define the $t_k$ in this case?  Answer-- you can't.  For future reference, according to the rules of the site, you shouldn't ask new questions in comments.  If you have another question, post it as a different question.

Comment: I understand, but could you please answer my last doubt? So a function is piecewise-continous even if the endpoints are not defined?

Comment: Yes, that's right.  There can be finitely many points in the interval, including the endpoints of the interval, where the function is not defined, so long as the one-sided limits exist.  (This wouldn't be a separate question anyway.  You can ask for additional info, or clarification, about the same question.)

Comment: Where else can a piecewise-continous function not be defined in the interval but at the end points?

Comment: I though you were talking about the endpoints of the interval $[a,b]$ that is, the points $a$ and $b$.  The other points are interior points of this interval, though they are endpoints of the subintervals constituting the domain.  I'm not sure what you mean by "the endpoints are not defined."  The endpoints must be well-defined.  It's the function that's not defined at those points.

Comment: "Yes, that's right. There can be finitely many points in the interval, including the endpoints of the interval, where the function is not defined, so long as the one-sided limits exist."So in the first picture, if the function goes to infinity at point t=1, then it's not piecewise continous in the interval [1,6], but it would be piecewise-continous in the inteval (1,6]. Is that right?

Comment: Now that you mention it, I think most people would say infinite limits count.  For example, I would say that the tangent function is piecewise continuous on the whole real line.  It's always best to look carefully at what definition a particular author is using.  [Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PiecewiseContinuous.html) gives a much simpler definition, which would clearly allow for infinite limits, and even cases where the limits don't exist.

Comment: That (existence or not of one-side limits in order to be piecewise continous) is confusing for me and I can't find I clear answer to that. I remember from the Laplace transforms classes, that if one of the endpoints [a,b] of the piecewise continous function goes to infinity, you can't claim that the Laplace transform exists.
One last doubt, could you please explain what "well-defined means? (in "The endpoints must be well-defined.")

Comment: Different authors may use the same term in different ways.  It always pays to check.  As far as "well-defined" goes, in this context it just means that they're specified.